# SerialPort.DataReceived and File Output

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I am creating a vb.net windows application to do a number of things including downloading a bunch of data from an EEProm and then saving that to a file.  I'm using the DataReceived routine to trap the incoming data then trying to write every 16 bytes out to a binary file.  I can write to the file fine normally, however I seem to be having issues with cross threading, etc which I'm not too familiar with.  The progress bar works fine, so all I need to be able to do now is to write the 16 bytes out to a file.

```
Private Sub btnTestCom_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnTestCom.Click

    Dim BaseFolder As String = "c:\"
    CurrentFileName = BaseFolder + "byteArray1.dat"
    Dim fStream As New FileStream(CurrentFileName, FileMode.Truncate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite)
    fStream.Close()

    uart_operation = 2
    DayNum = 0

    If mySerialPort.IsOpen() Then mySerialPort.Close()

    mySerialPort.BaudRate = 256000
    mySerialPort.Parity = Parity.None
    mySerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One
    mySerialPort.DataBits = 8
    mySerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None
    mySerialPort.Open()

    AddHandler mySerialPort.DataReceived, AddressOf mySerialPort_DataReceived

    'This is my start byte to the microprocessor
    Dim b() As Byte = New Byte() {254}
    mySerialPort.Write(b, 0, b.Length)
    mySerialPort.BaseStream.Flush()

End Sub

Private Delegate Sub UpdateProgressBar1(ByVal value As Integer)

Public Sub SetProgress(ByVal paramvalue As Integer)
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Me.Invoke(New UpdateProgressBar1(AddressOf Me.SetProgress), paramvalue)
    Else
        Me.ProgressBar1.Value = paramvalue
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub mySerialPort_DataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As SerialDataReceivedEventArgs)

    Dim tmpbyte As Byte
    fStream = New FileStream(CurrentFileName, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite)
    Dim bw As New BinaryWriter(fStream)

    'Try

    While mySerialPort.BytesToRead > 0
        Dim msgCharArray(255) As Char
        If mySerialPort.BytesToRead >= 256 Then
            mySerialPort.Read(msgCharArray, 0, 256)
        Else
            'mySerialPort.Read(msgCharArray, 0, mySerialPort.BytesToRead)
            Select Case uart_operation
                Case 2
                    If mySerialPort.ReadByte() = &HFF Then
                        uart_operation = 22
                    End If
                Case 22
                    tmpbyte = mySerialPort.ReadByte()
                    bytearray(bytecount) = tmpbyte
                    bytecount += 1

                    If bytecount = 16 Then
                        bw.Write(bytearray)
                        bytecount = 0
                        DayNum += 1
                        Dim b() As Byte = New Byte() {255}
                        mySerialPort.Write(b, 0, b.Length)
                        mySerialPort.BaseStream.Flush()

                        If DayNum = 366 Then
                            Me.SetProgress(DayNum)
                            MsgBox("Done")
                            Me.SetProgress(0)

                            bw.Close()
                            fStream.Close()
                            bw = Nothing
                            fStream = Nothing

                        Else
                            Me.SetProgress(DayNum)
                        End If

                    End If

            End Select

        End If
    End While
    'Catch ex As Exception
    '   MessageBox.Show("Exception Occured: " + ex.Message)
    'End Try
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: How does your "issue" look? You get an exception (which one?)? Filecontent not what you expect? Something else?

Comment: The DataReceived event fires many times, typically once for each received byte.  So don't create the file in the event handler, create it when you open the port.